# How do I customize margin values in unocss?

Tags: tailwind-css, windicss, unocss

How do I customize the margin value

The default margins for `mr` `mt` `ml` `mb` is 1em，How can I set these margins to use 18px or 20px? I'd also like to do something similar with padding.

```
my: margin : 20px 0
mx: margin : 0 20px
ml : margin-left: 20px
mt: margin-top: 20px
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by customizing your theme.

You can customize your spacing scale by editing `theme.spacing` or `theme.extend.spacing` in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '20px': '20px',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can customize just the margin scale by editing `theme.margin` or `theme.extend.margin` in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      margin: {
        '18px': '18px',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, if you don't want to modify your theme, you can use arbitrary values for the utility classes, such as `m-[20px]` or `my-[18px]`.

Resource: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin#customizing-your-theme

Answer (score 0):

you may use next:

```
m-10px or m10px     -> margin: 10px
my-20px or my20px   -> margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px
mr-20px or mr20px   -> margin-right: 20px 0
```

if you don't want to use `px` in your styles
OR if you want to set other sides (that are not mentioned) as `0`
as: `mr-20px   -> margin: 0 20px 0 0`

then you may use custom rules:

```
marginSideMap = {
  l: `0 0 0 ${value}px`,
  r: `0 ${value}px 0 0`,
  t: `${value}px 0 0`,
  b: `0 0 ${value}px`,
  y: `0 ${value}px`,
  x: `${value}px 0`,
  default: `${value}px`
}  
const formatMargin = (_, side, value) => ({
  margin: `${marginSideMap[side || 'default']`,
})

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  rules: [
    [/^m([trblxy])?-?(\d+)$/, formatMargin],
  ],
})
```

it will grab any of the next value: m-20, mx20, mr-20 ... and apply this formatter.